# JQGrid and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I am trying to get this awesome [JQuery plugin](http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/docs/jqGrid/jqGrid.html) working with SQL Server. I have setup PDO as I use it elsewhere (with MS Access) - I think I have it setup with sql server (2008) now. Here is how I connect:

```
define('DB_DSN',"odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyInstance;Database=table1;");
define('DB_USER', ''); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

// include the jqGrid Class
require_once "php/jqGrid.php";
// include the PDO driver class
require_once "php/jqGridPdo.php";
// Connection to the server
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
// Tell the db that we use utf-8
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");
// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
$tsql = 'SELECT * FROM Trt';
// Write the SQL Query
$grid->SelectCommand = $tsql;
// set the ouput format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
// Let the grid create the model
$grid->setColModel();
// Set the url from where we obtain the data
$grid->setUrl('report-creator.php');

// Set grid caption using the option caption
$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "caption"=>"Report",
    "rowNum"=>10,
    "sortname"=>"OrderID",
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,50),
    ));

$grid->toolbarfilter = true;
$grid->setFilterOptions(array("stringResult"=>true));
$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$conn = null;
```

I get this error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver
 does not support this function: driver doesn't support meta data' in  
C:\wamp\www\webs\tgd\edh\php\jqGridPdo.php(1) : eval()'d code:1 Stack trace: #0 
C:\wamp\www\webs\tgd\edh\php\jqGridPdo.php(1) : eval()'d code(1): PDOStatement-
    >getColumnMeta(0) #1 C:\wamp\www\webs\tgd\edh\php\jqGrid.php(1) : eval()'d code(7):  
jqGridDB->getColumnMeta(0, Object(PDOStatement)) #2 C:\wamp\www\webs\tgd\Front- End\report-
creator.php(31): jqGridRender->setColModel() #3 C:\wamp\www\webs\tgd\Front- End\view-
report.php(123): require_once('C:\wamp\www\web...') #4 {main} thrown in  
C:\wamp\www\webs\tgd\edh\php\jqGridPdo.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

I appreciate any help - I just can't understand the problem. I have narrowed it down to this function: `$grid->SelectCommand` - if I remove this no error occurs but I can not do without this as this is where my t-sql to query the database goes.

I am able to query SQL server mysql using `PDQ->Query('SELECT * FROM table1')`.

Thanks all

*Please note: I have edited table name, file paths for privacy. :)*

Comment: I do not see SelectCommand in the block of code you pasted. As it is the offending code, it would be helpful if you added it back in.

Comment: I apologise, I have added this in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this so I switched over to another class which was written by the JQGrid guys that makes use of the PHP driver from Microsoft. This solved my problem, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jqGrid uses getColumnMeta function to enumerate columns, but this function [may be unsupported](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) by several drivers - in this case, your MSSQL driver.

See examples in the link above to test if getColumnMeta works.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Trirand (the company that developers jqGrid - ASP.NET team) and unfortunately cannot help with PHP much, but I can suggest posting the very same question in our own forums as well:

http://www.trirand.net/forum/

there you will find a PHP jqGrid forum and you will get a timely response from our PHP team. Meanwhile I will write them an email and ask them to help here as well, but just in case posting there will guarantee you an answer.

Cheers,
Rumen Stankov
Trirand Inc